# How to have three power plans in OS X?

Tags: macos, power-management, osx-lion

so I got a Mac (yaay) and hit a problem with power plan management.

Basically I need three plans:

1. I'm on cord, don't care about battery life.
2. I'm on battery, don't care about battery life since the cord is somewhere near.
3. I'm on battery away from power and I want my laptop to last as long as possible.

And OS X Lion apparently has two power plans, on battery/on cord.

What can I do?

Comment: What do you want these plans to do for you in each case?

Comment: the first ones to have max brightness and never go to sleep.
the last one to have minimal brightness, turn off wifi, and do whatever else is possible to conserve energy (throttle cpu maybe)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this from System Preferences, but there is a *pmset* terminal command that can set everything Enerygy Saver prefrence pane can, and more.  You could put settings in a script that you could run for different situations.  If you run `pmset -g` in the terminal, it will show you what the current settings are.

Comment: Combine this with tools such as [Marco Polo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/) for some partial automation (e.g. specific home wifi = "near power cable", otherwise on battery = preservation mode).

Comment: Are you guys aware of any other tool to manage power profiles? I'm sure I've seen one before, but can't recall its name.